# Formatting a date and time with periods as separators

Tags: python

I am trying to apply current time and date in a Windows application using Python. I used the following code:

```
current_time = str(time.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %H:%M"))

type(waitForObject("{name='TextBoxSampleName'}"), "Test." + current_time)
```

but when I run  the script I see the following format

`27Test.06.03.2016 10` (the hours and minutes are separated for some reason)

I want the final result to be `Test.06.03.2016.10:27`

Comment: what is `waitForObject`

Comment: well first of all you have space between date and time in your pattern. Amend it.

Comment: When I run `time.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %H:%M")` I get `'06.03.2016 13:44'` - if that isn't what you're seeing your bug is elsewhere. If that isn't what you want, your format string is wrong.

Comment: Why are you calling `type`?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `waitForObject` is, we can still get the output you desire.

First, there is a minor formatting mistake in your `current_time =` line:

```
current_time = str(time.strftime("%m.%d.%Y.%H:%M"))
                                          ^-- Add this period to get the format you want
```

Next, the second line can simply be (or you can assign it to a variable for later use):

```
print("Test."+current_time)
```

These two changes will print out something like this:

```
Test.06.03.2016.12:42
```